# Require_once in PHP causing crash

Tags: php

I am attempting to include a PHP file that contains a class that I would like to use.  My main file includes:

```
<?php
    echo "main started"
    require_once("mysqli.php");
    echo "File Included";
?>
```

mysqli.php (which is located in the same folder as the main file):

```
<?php
    echo "Mysqli_connector"
    class Mysqli_connector {

} // end of class
?>
```

I output `main started` and then the program ends with no errors or warnings that I can see.  Is there a problem with include files with classes in PHP? I am a C++ coder 95% of the time, so I'm not used to PHP querks.

Comment: If you'd said `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);` before the `require_once`, you'd almost certainly see a message about a parse error.  Reason #184 why you should have error reporting cranked up on your dev server.

Comment: Please don't correct the code you're asking about...doing so invalidates the answer.  If you want to mention what you've fixed, add an updated version or describe the changes.  (But the answers will already say what to change, so even that shouldn't be necessary.)

Answer (score 9):

```
echo "Mysqli_connector" // <-- missing closing semi-colon
```

You're also going to want to make sure you have [display errors on and set to show all errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025).

Comment: I have been coding for 6 years, and yet I still make idiot mistakes.  Thanks for the assist.

Comment: Also missing one (a semicolon) after `echo "main started"`

Comment: @PatrickQ: That one is almost certainly a typo in the question.  If it were actually in the main script, the first echo wouldn't have happened.

Comment: Ok, after fixing that I now output both `main started` and `mysqli_connector`, but not `file included`.

Comment: Also, using an IDE like Netbeans would have told you where the error was before you even tried to execute it.

Comment: I suspect an error in the mysqli file. Have you verified error reporting is on?

Comment: Oh I got it.  I turned error reporting on and just didn't line the files up correctly.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: Using the display errors directives can really help you out of a needlessly annoying situation!